# Is there an element that I can use to enclose <li> elements with other than <ul> or <ol>?

Tags: html

I have the following:

```
<ul id="status-infos">
   <li>x</li>
   <li>y</li> 
</ul>
```

Is there any legal element that I can use to enclose the `<li>` elements. For example:

```
<ul id="status-infos">
  <xxx id="xxx">
   <li>x</li>
   <li>y</li> 
  </xxx>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you trying to have the list broken down into sections?  You can nest lists inside of lists if you are trying to do that.  Here is a link to w3schools that has the types of lists you can use: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

Comment: No there is no legal element like u r saying. But you can make lists inside lists like <ul><li><ul>..</ul></li></ul>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML 5 the `<menu>` item can also be a parent of `li` elements.. (*but you cannot use the `menu` as a child of `ul`/`ol`. You can only use it **instead** of them*)

The specs are http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html

Comment: This then seems rather pointless in terms of what the OP is trying to do. I wonder why (s)he accepted it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use another `ul`:

```
<ul id="status-infos">
  <li>
      <ul id="xxx">
          <li>x</li>
          <li>y</li> 
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I suspect your problem really is:

> Is there a way I can CSS hook a contiguous block of list items in my
>   list

Well, you could give them all class names, or go for more creative solutions like `nth-child` ranges. Say you wanted to apply some CSS to all list items between the 4th and 7th ones. You would use:

```
li:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+7){
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By HTML specifications, `li` elements may also appear as children of `menu` and `dir` elements. But this is of little use, since those elements were meant to be presentational variants of `ul` and didn’t become even that (they are rendered normally the same way as `ul`). The new meaning of `menu` in HTML5 drafts is a different matter, but also not relevant here.

I suggest that you ask a different question that specifies what you wish to achieve, rather than an assumed solution (that cannot work) to an unspecified problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your only desire is to have an additional wrapper for the styling hook (why?) for the `<li>`, the correct course of action would be to wrap the `<ul>` with a container:

```
  <div id="xxx_container">
      <ul id="xxx">
          <li>x</li>
          <li>y</li> 
      </ul>
  </div>
```